# How can I add class attributes to Models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django to build an internal webapp where devices and analysis reports on those devices are managed.
Currently an abstract Analysis is defined like this:

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    dut = models.ForeignKey(Dut) # Device Under Test
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    raw_data = models.FileField(upload_to="analysis")
    public = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def analysis_type(self):
        s = str(self.__class__)
        class_name = s.split('.')[-1][:-2] # Get latest name in dotted class name as remove '> at end
        return AnalysisType.objects.get(name=class_name)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

There are then a number of different analysis types that can be done on a device, with different resulting data.

```
class ColorAnalysis(Analysis):       
    value1 = models.FloatField()
    value2 = models.FloatField()
    ...

class DurabilityAnalysis(Analysis):       
    value1 = models.FloatField()
    value2 = models.FloatField()
    ...    

...
```

Each such analysis is created from an Excel sheet posted by the operator. There exists an Excel template the operator fills in for each analysis type.
(The issue here is not if data input should be done in a web form, there are lots of reasons to choose the Excel path)
On a page on the website all analysis types should be listed along with a link to the corresponding Excel sheet template used to report that analysis.

Currently I have defined something like

```
class AnalysisType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256 )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024,blank=True )
    template = models.FileField(upload_to="analysis_templates")
```

but when I though about how I would link this data to the different analysis result model classes I though that what I want to do is to add this data as class attributes to each analysis type.
The problem is that the class attributes are already used by the django magic to define the data of each instance.

How do I add "class attributes" to django models? Any other ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT:
Now added the analysis_type property by looking up the class name. This requires no manual adding of a variable to each sub-class. Works fine, but still requires manual adding of an entry of AnalysisType corresponding to each sub-class. It would be nice if this could be handled by the class system as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

How about a property or method that returns an AnalysisType dependent on an attribute in the particular Analysis subclass?

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def analysis_type(self):
        return AnalysisType.objects.get(name=self.analysis_type_name)

class ColorAnalysis(Analysis):
    analysis_type_name = 'color'

class DurabilityAnalysis(Analysis):
    analysis_type_name = 'durability'
```

Comment: Yes. That would probably work. Even better would be to get the class name instead of your "analysis_type_name". I would like the normal class system to handle as much as possible.